# React NextJS CSS - Section's height is set to 100% of parent height, but gives 100% of page height

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with transferring a project to NextJS (was using Create-React-App previously).

In NextJS for some reason, when I set the height of a section to 100%, it acts as 100% of the total page height and not taking to account the header & footer.
I do this because I want the minimum height of the content to fit perfectly, so the Footer is always aligned to the bottom of the screen.
This is a picture of what's happening:
[section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVjgH.png)

As you can see, the section takes up 100% of the page while there's a navbar with at least 5rem in height, and a footer with at least 20rem in height.

This is the HTML structure:
[HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNVL9.png)

and as you can see, the Navbar, Section and footer are all under the same div ("__next") which has the height set to 100% as well.

I can't seem to figure out what's happening and why the section is 100% of the viewport height instead of the available space.

Any help would be appreciated!

Code references:

```css
/* Setting the height of all direct children of body (the __next div) */
body > div {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Setting the height of the section */
section {
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding the following to set the height of the div as well as the display to flex & direction to column:

```css
#__next {
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

then I simply removed this code:

```css
body > div {
  height: 100%;
}
```